# Is there a way to try to run an ansible task, role, or play again on a different host if it failed?

Tags: ansible, automation

I have two master/master LDAP servers and an Ansible play that creates a new LDAP user.

I would like for the play to run on the first LDAP server.

- If the first host run is successful, skip running on second host.
- If the first host run is **not** successful, run on second host.

Answer (score 0):

Run the play against a service address that is in front of both LDAP servers. Load balancer, DNS round robin, whatever. You can execute the play again later after you fix any problem with your directory.

While there is an error handling mechanism with `block:` and `rescue:`, Ansible itself does not seem like the best place to insert high availability for your infrastructure.